# Get thumbnails from RSS feed UWP C# Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, rss, uwp

I am using this project :
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-rssreader

I want to get thumnails from a RSS feed. Now, the problem is I get errors. I will explain them. First have a look on so far what I did. :
I have this class :

```
  public class ArticleViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public Uri Link { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset PublishedDate { get; set; }
    public string PublishedDateFormatted => PublishedDate.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy    h:mm tt").ToUpper();
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => 
        obj is ArticleViewModel ? (obj as ArticleViewModel).GetHashCode() == GetHashCode() : false;
    public override int GetHashCode() => Link.GetHashCode();
    private bool? _isStarred = false;
    public bool? IsStarred { get { return _isStarred; } set { SetProperty(ref _isStarred, value); } }
}
```

For example we take the RSS feed of http://coffeeetech.xyz/feed.

Now here :

var feed = await new SyndicationClient().RetrieveFeedAsync(feedViewModel.Link);

```
                feedViewModel.Name = String.IsNullOrEmpty(feedViewModel.Name) ? feed.Title.Text : feedViewModel.Name;
                feedViewModel.Description = feed.Subtitle?.Text ?? String.Empty;

                feed.Items.Select(item => new ArticleViewModel
                {


                    thumbnail = item.thumbnail,
                    //    description = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(description);
                    Title = item.Title.Text,
                    Summary = item.Summary == null ? string.Empty :
                        item.Summary.Text.RegexRemove("\\&.{0,4}\\;").RegexRemove("<.*?>"),
                    Author = item.Authors.Select(a => a.NodeValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Link = item.ItemUri ?? item.Links.Select(l => l.Uri).FirstOrDefault(),
                    PublishedDate = item.PublishedDate
                })
                .ToList().ForEach(article =>
                {
                    var favorites = AppShell.Current.ViewModel.FavoritesFeed;
                    var existingCopy = favorites.Articles.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Equals(article));
                    article = existingCopy ?? article;
                    if (!feedViewModel.Articles.Contains(article)) feedViewModel.Articles.Add(article);
                });
                return true;
```

Now, the problem is that, in the line thubmnail = item.thumbnail, I get the error that 'thumbnail doesn't exist in current context'

So the question is how to get the thumbnail via SyndicationFeed. I mean, the item thumbnail doesn't exist there.
Thanks.

Comment: The type of the `item` you've used is [SyndicationItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br243533). As you can see, there is no thumbnail property in this class. When I use the code you've posted, I get following error:"'SyndicationItem' does not contain a definition for 'thumbnail' and no extension method 'thumbnail' accepting a first argument of type 'SyndicationItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ". Do you change any other code? And which thumbnail you want to get? Is the **image** under **channel**?

Comment: That is my question. How to add something like thumbnail in Syndication class. I want to get the main thumbnail images.

Answer (score 0):

[SyndicationItem class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.syndication.syndicationitem.aspx) represents an item in the feed. This class encapsulates information in the **/rss/channel/item** element in *RSS 2.0* or the **atom:entry** element in *Atom 1.0*.

For the [`<item>` element](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html#hrelementsOfLtitemgt) in RSS 2.0, there is no sub-element related to thumbnail. So `SyndicationItem` do not has a "thumbnail" property. And even we add a "thumbnail" property in this class, it also won't help. For the mapping between `SyndicationItem` properties and RSS elements, please see the table under the **Remarks** section of [SyndicationItem class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.syndication.syndicationitem.aspx).

Since you want to get the main thumbnail images. I suppose you want to get the `<image>` sub-element of `<channel>`. If so, you can try with `SyndicationFeed.ImageUri` property. This property represents **image/uri** element in *RSS 2.0*. You can add a "thumbnail" property in `FeedViewModel` and then set it in `RefreshAsync` method like following.

```
var feed = await new SyndicationClient().RetrieveFeedAsync(feedViewModel.Link);

feedViewModel.Name = String.IsNullOrEmpty(feedViewModel.Name) ? feed.Title.Text : feedViewModel.Name;
feedViewModel.Description = feed.Subtitle?.Text ?? String.Empty;
feedViewModel.thumbnail = feed.ImageUri;
```